# How to get the instance of the class of a component in angular by selector id as a key?

Tags: angular, typescript

Suppose I have a component whose selector is `child` and its class name is `ChildComponent`.

To get the instance of `ChildComponent` class in `AppComponent` class, I can `import {ChildComponent} from ./child/child.component.ts` in the `app.component.ts` file. But I don't want to import the instance. I want to get the instance by selector id.

Suppose a function `getComponentReferenceById(selector: string)` in `AppComponent` that takes the selector as parameter and returns the instance of `ChildComponent` class. Is there any way to do it in angular?

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that in your AppComponent you have (or will have) an instance of the ChildComponet, you can use @ViewChild to access to the instance, properties and methods of the ChildComponet:

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild